# Remote desktop connection (vnc) keeps working when restarting iis?

Tags: iis, vnc

maby it's a simple question. I would like to reset iis on a windows 2003 server via VNC. Doing so would i loose the vnc contact with server during the process? Thank you

Comment: Learn how to accept an answer please.

Answer (score 2):

No, restarting IIS does not affect RDC. IIS is a Web Server, where Remote Desktop is a Remote Desktop Connection (RDC). These two services are entirely independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

*Remote Desktop Protocol* (RDP) is a built-in Microsoft feature, the one you use with *Remote Desktop Connection* client (`mstsc`), while *Virtual Network Computing* (VNC) is a 3rd party tool with several implementations like RealVNC / TightVNC / ***VNC... They are two different protocols and your question doesn't state clearly which one you are actually using.

However, the answer is the same: both RDP and VNC are independent from IIS Web Server and restarting or even removing the IIS shouldn't cause losing connection to the server.

You should be aware that Windows 2003 Server has been EOL since July 2015 and won't get any security updates. You shouldn't be using it anymore, and it's dangerous to use it as a web server!

Comment: You are right and we are setting up a new server right now. Thank you very much for your clear explanations.